# Setting and using attribute of dynamically created variable in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript/JQuery which allows me to create a new entry in an HTML ordered list. This works fine. But **now I am trying to set each entry to have an id equal to a variable 'id''s value**, so that I can **identify an entry and remove its id from a javascript array**.

I am being told that I can't use setAttribute OR defineProperty, so I don't know what to do! I am including both my attempts to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
var idList = []; //array of entry ids

$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;

        var list = $("#list"); //works fine
        var name = $("#colleague-select option:selected").text(); //works fine
        var id = $("#colleague-select").val(); //works fine

        var remove = "<button type='button' class='remove-me'> X </button>"; //works fine
        var entry = "<li>" + name + remove+ "</li>"; //works fine



        //entry.setAttribute("id", id); //doesn't work

        //or

        Object.defineProperty(entry, 'id', {
            get: function(){return id;},
            set: function(value) {id = value;}
        });


        list.append(entry); //adds entry to HTML element 'list'


        idList.push(id); //adds id to array which should be the same as entry's id

        return false;
    });
});


$(document).on('click', ".remove-me", function(){
    var entry = $(this).parent();
    entry.remove();

    var id = entry.attr("id"); //gets value of attribute "id". How will this need to be changed?
    var index = idList.indexOf(id); //finds the index number of id within array

    idList.splice(index,1); //removes id from array

});
```

Help on how to do this will be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry is a string of html not an dom node, you can create an jQuery object out of it and then add the attribute or just add the id in the string

```
var entry = $("<li>" + name + remove+ "</li>").attr('id', id); //works fine
```

or

```
var entry = "<li id=\""+id+"\">" + name + remove+ "</li>"; //works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

The click event on `.remove-me` doesn't work because you're calling `entry.remove()` and afterwards `entry.attr("id")`. At that point the entry element has been removed and thus you can't the get the id.

Move `entry.remove()` below `entry.attr("id")`.

Comment: ok thanks. This would only work using Musa's first answer, right?

Comment: Yes, the id attribute would need to be set beforehand.